# Convert SQL query to SQLAlchemy query

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have two SQLALchemy models with a many-to-many relationship between them:

```
class Contact(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer)    
    users = db.relationship(ContactUser, cascade='all, delete-orphan')

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class ContactUser(db.Model):
    contact_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('contact.id'), 
                           primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), 
                        primary_key=True)
    user = db.relationship(User)
```

I want to convert this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    c.* 
FROM 
    contact c LEFT JOIN 
        user_contact uc ON c.id = uc.contact_id AND uc.user_id='456'
WHERE 
    c.customer_id = '123' AND 
    uc.contact_id IS NULL
```

Into an SQLAlchemy query, where I can specify `customer_id` and `user_id`.

I can't figure out how to tell SQLAlchemy to add the `AND uc.user_id='456'` to the ON clause.

Current query:

```
contacts = (Contact.query.join(ContactUser)
            .filter(Contact.customer_id == customer.id)
            .filter(ContactUser.contact_id == None)
```

The docs mention something about being able to use a "two argument calling of join", but it seems that only allows me to specify one thing, and I need two in my ON clause.

Also, I think I need to use `outerjoin` instead of `join`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the guys in #sqlalchemy, we came up with:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_

...

Contact.query.filter(
    Contact.customer_id==customer_id)
    .outerjoin(ContactUser, and_(Contact.id==ContactUser.contact_id,
                                 ContactUser.user_id!=user_id))
    .filter(ContactUser.contact_id == None))
```